# Changing locale on Heroku rails at runtime

Tags: heroku, localization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My dev environment allows me to change my app locale in a controller by setting

```
I18n.locale = 'fr'
```

It works on both dev and prod env on my laptop, but if I were to deploy it on Heroku it no longer works, as if the changes are disregarded. Someone might know why?

p.s: If I preset the default_locale in the initializer both versions of the site (in my case English and French) work. But the switching at runtime doesn't

Comment: The [**Rails Guides on Internationalization**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale) should hold many of the things you are looking for. It gives a lot of options and examples how you can set the locale depending on e.g. URL parameters (`http://mysite.com/?lang=fr`), domain names, subdomains and more. If you have any more specific needs, feel free to ask again.

Comment: The problem wasn't related to that. I failed to explain that I was building an app on Spree and their localization works based on the ```session[:locale]``` variable. I had to set that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't related to that. I failed to explain that I was building an app on Spree and their localization works based on the `session[:locale]` variable. I had to set that first.